# Parse Data base with iOS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, database, parse-platform

I've created an iOS application and a little web-app. The web-app takes input and creates objects of class ("Jobs") in my parse DB. The iOS app then reads these jobs from the database (With all sorts of functionality).

Now, this is the concept and I've had both parts working separately but they won't work together.

```
// Function called to save all the information gathered.
function submitFunction (name, phone, email, title, date, start, hours, address, notes) {

  console.log("worked");
  var Jobs = Parse.Object.extend("Jobs");
  var jobs = new Jobs();


  jobs.save({
  // these need to change to variables
    name: name,
    phoneNumber: Number(phone),
    email: email,
    date: date,
    title:title,
    startTime: start,
    numofHours: Number(hours),
    address: address,
    notes: notes 

  }, {
    success: function(name) {
      // The object was saved successfully.
    },
    error: function(name, error) {
      // The save failed.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
    }
  });
}
```

This is a snippet of the javascript from my web-app, but when these are added to the DB, when i try to retrieve data my iOS app crashes (and vice versa).

The Xcode query looks like this:

```
PFQuery *updateTableArray = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Jobs"];
    [updateTableArray findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d objects.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                //Init variables from parse
                NSString *titleString = object[@"title"];
                NSString *dateString = object[@"date"];
                NSString *timeString = object[@"startTime"];
                NSString *hoursString = object[@"numofHours"];
                NSString *addressString = object[@"address"];
                NSString *notesString = object[@"notes"];
                NSString *phoneString = object[@"phoneNumber"];
                NSString *objectIdString = object.objectId;

                //add initialized vars into appropriate arrays
                [self.titlesArray addObject:titleString];
                [self.dateArray addObject:dateString];
                [self.timeArray addObject:timeString];
                [self.hoursArray addObject:hoursString];
                [self.addressArray addObject:addressString];
                [self.notesArray addObject:notesString];
                [self.phoneArray addObject:phoneString];
                [self.objectIdArray addObject:objectIdString];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

There were some funny compatabilities in xcode, thus the creations of the stings. Anyway, when this is ran (upon the opening of the view) it crashes with an error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd629260'

Comment: Add the (complete) code for the query you are doing on iOS that is crashing, the exception message it is crashing with and you get help. Adding the JavaScript code when your iOS app is actually crashing makes it very hard to debug ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was conflicting datatypes. casting all uploaded data in JS to strings fixes the compatibility for reading it with the iOS side.